# Gitlab CI : git pull don't work correctly (infinite loop)

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Git pull don't work correctly and i got an infinite loop with the gitlab runner ci
*(I talk here about the last step of deploy)*

All i need is to open a directory in the server and make a git pull automatically with gitlab ci

This my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
test1:
  tags:
    - qdf
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Do a test here"

test2:
  tags:
    - qdf
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Do another parallel test here"

deploy1:
  tags:
    - qdf
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Start deploy"
    - cd D:/Git/Prod
    - echo "Next step"
    - git pull
    - echo "finish"
```

[image]

What i'm doing wrong and what i'm missing in my gitlab-ci file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an authenfication issue.

The solution is to use a git config before the git pull like

`git config remote.origin.url https://$(USER):$(PASS)@github.com/<UserNAME>/<Project>.git`